# How do I test for differences in cost per acquisition (CPA) in an A/B test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test

How would I go about testing for differences in cost per acquisition (CPA) in an A/B test?

I'm a huge novice and am unsure if I would use some kind of t-test or chi-square test (or neither) to compare the proportion of cost per acquisition in group A to cost per acquisition in group B.

e.g.

**Group A:**

Cost: £1500

Acquisitions: 30

CPA: £50

**Group B:**

Cost: £3000

Acuisitions: 50

CPA: £60

For context, this is an experiment for a digital advertising campaign and has associated clicks and impressions. Cost is determined by click volume and cost per click.

Any help would be super appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  For testing between proportions, you would want to use the $\chi^2$ test for goodness of fit.  That being said, I have not dealt with CPA, so there might be a better approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

T-Test, when testing difference in cost efficiency metrics you use the dollars as your sample input and then the volume metric (in this case acquisitions) as your result input.

Group A:
Sample is 1,500
Result is 30

Group B
Sample is 3000
Result is 50

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/317134)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).